# NGINX rewrite issue

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, slim

I have NGINX + PHP5-fpm and `slim` for routing, my website wont work with out this rewrite : `try_files $uri /index.php;` , now everything is fine and all site is ok except some API, for example `http://example.com/webservice/android.php/get_video_info`
It doesn't work and say it :`No input file specified.`
Why ? i should mention that `http://example.com/webservice/android.php` is exist on server but "http://example.com/webservice/android.php/get_video_info" is not exist and its just a post action on this `android.php`

PS : if you need more information i will provide for you

Comment: Please look at our docs: http://www.slimframework.com/docs/start/web-servers.html

Comment: post full code....

Comment: How are `android.php` and `index.php` related?

Answer (score 0):

It was about my app.config, after I checked the NGINX log i found that the issue it's make path duplicated like `/var/www//var/www/` after i change my config and remove second one, issue is solved